# Puppeteer Throwing Invalid Parameters Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, chromium, puppeteer

I am trying to convert an HTML content to PDF, but I am getting Invalid parameters for scale and preferCSSPageSize when passed using variables.

Error Message:

> Error: Protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Invalid parameters scale: double value expected; preferCSSPageSize: boolean value expected
>       at Promise (/home/santhosh-4759/Downloads/node-v8.11.3-linux-x64/bin/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:202:56)
>       at new Promise ()

Command Used:

```
./node puppeteerpdf.js test.pdf 1 false '' '' false false 210mm 297mm 0 0 0 0 false 'htmlcontent'
```

This doesn't work:

```
await page.pdf({path: output, scale: vcale, displayHeaderFooter: displayHeaderFooter, headerTemplate: headerTemplate, footerTemplate: footerTemplate, printBackground: printBackground, landscape: landscape, width: width, height: height, margin: marginParams, preferCSSPageSize: preferCSSPageSize});
```

This is working:

```
await page.pdf({path: output, scale: 1, displayHeaderFooter: displayHeaderFooter, headerTemplate: headerTemplate, footerTemplate: footerTemplate, printBackground: printBackground, landscape: landscape, width: width, height: height, margin: marginParams, preferCSSPageSize: false});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the variables you are passing to [`page.pdf()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions) as the values for `scale` and `preferCSSPageSize` are not of the correct type.

Your working example shows `scale` to be equal to `1` and `preferCSSPageSize` to be equal to `false`.

These are the **default values** of these parameters, so you could safely exclude them from the options passed to `page.pdf()`.

If these values can change, and you are obtaining the values of these attributes from the command line, make sure to convert them from a string to the correct type before sending them to `page.pdf()`:

```
vcale = parseInt(vcale);
preferCSSPageSize = preferCSSPageSize === 'true';
```

Comment: Thanks, Miller, it works. As you said those values could change so only exposed it to args.