# What is the Dockerfile to use node:12-alpine with puppeteer@1.19?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, puppeteer

Since I faced puppeteer@1.13 error when printing pdf with lots of photos(at least need to renew the lock):

> when running in Dev, there was exception:
>   (node:17) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Page crashed!
>     at Page._onTargetCrashed  (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:176:24)

So I would like to use latest version of puppeteer@1.19. However, when I changed to use that, there is error :

```
Line239: await page.pdf({
            path: TEMP_DIR + filename, 
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true
         });
```

> printPdf() Error
>   Error: Protocol error (IO.read): Invalid parameters handle: string value expected
>        at /usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:183:56
>        at new Promise ()
>        at CDPSession.send (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:182:12)
>        at Function.readProtocolStream (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:241:37)
>        at async Page.pdf (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:988:12)
>        at async printPdf (/usr/src/app/puppeteer.js:239:9)
>        at async /usr/src/app/puppeteer.js:129:21
>      -- ASYNC --
>        at Page. (/usr/src/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
>        at printPdf (/usr/src/app/puppeteer.js:239:20)
>        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
>        at async /usr/src/app/puppeteer.js:129:21 {
>     message: 'Protocol error (IO.read): Invalid parameters handle: string value expected'
>   }

How can I prepare Dockerfile to support puppeteer@1.19 or solve this error? Thanks.

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910292/puppeteer-throwing-invalid-parameters-error? or how i can try your code?

Comment: Hi @Adiii, below is my code:
    await page.pdf({
            scale: 1,
            preferCSSPageSize: false,
            path: '/tmp/test.pdf', 
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true // required for photos otherwise blank
        });

but still with mentioned error